# How to get a layout's dimension or more like the height and witdth in pixels?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I want to get a layout's width in pixels.
I tried this:

```
LinearLayout galleryContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.galleryContainerLayout);
int galleryWidth= galleryContainer.getLayoutParams().width;
```

if i toast out galleryWidth, it is says "-1".

I also tried

```
galleryContainer.getWidth()
```

but it is gives 0 at the first time, then 480 (the actual size) at second time, so it is like i got the pixels BEFORE my layout infiltrate its size.

What the hell?

How can i really get a layouts width in pixels ? Or some exact values like dip?

Answer (score 3):

Use `measure()` before call `getWidth()`

```
galleryContainer.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: getting crash without excepetion with this code.
What are the .FILL_PARENT tags for ?
My galleryContainer doesnt have fill_parent width and heigths. Both of them are match_parent.

Comment: there are three ways to grab outfit in screen for every widget::
FILL_PARENT = to grab the full available screen, 
WRAP_CONTENT = to garb the required screen for the current widget, 
Manual Size e.g. "10dp"/"10px" = as per your choice. Hope you get what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

The layout is inflated but not yet drawn.In order to get width or height, you will have to use the below method.

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     System.out.println("...Width..."+galleryContainer.getWidth()); 
}
```

Comment: The method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) of type ShopActivity.SendRating must override or implement a supertype method

Why im getting this error if it is already overrided ?

The more stranger, that eclipse suggests me to do this:

1 quick fix: -Remove override annotation.

What the..?

Comment: r u using this method in a activity or non-activity class?. This problem is likely to occur if your java compliance is 1.6 or low. You have to change it to 1.7. or try to remove the override annotation and check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for you but we can code something like this too, check out if it helps.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                        int width = display.getWidth();
                        int height = display.getHeight();
```

Have fun.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.